# Changing the texture of material

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'd first like to apologise beforehand if my question is very basic and dumb as I am very new to coding and unity/vuforia in general.

I'd like to track a custom image and display a quad under it (i've done this part). I've also managed to set the material/texture/look of the quad to a image located in my computer. However, when trying to do build into a android app, I am unable to set the file path correctly and it doesnt work.

I would like the material/texture/look of the quad to be constantly changing/updating, is this possible? I can constantly overwrite the image file on my computer/phone but will the photo update in the app itself?

Thank you so much for any help in advance!

A desperate student

```
   void Start()
    {

        string path = "file://storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.kenny.argame/files/im2.jpg";
        StartCoroutine(DownloadImage(path));
    }


    IEnumerator DownloadImage(string MediaUrl)
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material = FinalMaterialRef;

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(MediaUrl);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        else
            _material.mainTexture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
        FinalMaterialRef = _material;


    }

}
```

Comment: Is there an error message you might have?

Comment: there's no error when compiling but the material/texture/look of the quad is not changing/updating when i change the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not clear from your code where `_material` and `FinalMaterialRef` are originally declared -- they're not in the scope you showed -- you might have your references mixed up and overwrite them, but not the actual material. This works:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ChangeTexture : MonoBehaviour
{
    Material material = null;

    void Start()
    {
        material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

        const string path = "file://E:/_temp/1.jpg";
        StartCoroutine(DownloadAndAssignImage(path));
    }

    IEnumerator DownloadAndAssignImage(string mediaUrl)
    {
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(mediaUrl);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            material.mainTexture =
                ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much for taking the time to reply.

I tried the code you've kindly provided and it work in applying the image from my file as the material texture. However, when i overwrite the image (while the program is still running), the texture does not update itself (with the program still running as well)

Comment: Is there a way for the texture to update itself automatically (when the program is still running) when the image is overwritten?

Comment: How do you currently attempt to change it while running? Please edit your original question to add the relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently using a separate program outside of unity that uses a python code to take a screenshot and saving it as image (constantly overwriting the previous image)

Comment: Ok, but how do you then currently attempt to update the material again (i.e. reload the image and assign it to the material)?

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do that. Is there anyway I can modify the code to update the material consistently?

Comment: You could either have the external Python code inform your app in some way to retrigger material assignment, or your Unity code could check in given intervals the last save time of the image file, and update when needed. More approaches may be possible depending on the structure of your framework.

Comment: How could i modify the unity code such that it will check at intervals and update the image? thank you so much and sorry if im asking really basic questions